# Augmented reality, Stereoscopy, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, stereoscopy

I'm developing an augmented reality application. I need to add the stereoscopy vision on this application to use with cardboard, but i am not getting add the stereocopy vision on this code. Can Someone help me?
 I have three class, in which I put stereoscopy and how to do it?

```
public class ARSimpleApplication extends Application {

    private static Application sInstance;

    // Anywhere in the application where an instance is required, this method
    // can be used to retrieve it.
    public static Application getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); 
        sInstance = this;
        ((ARSimpleApplication) sInstance).initializeInstance();
    }

    // Here we do one-off initialisation which should apply to all activities
    // in the application.
    protected void initializeInstance() {

        // Unpack assets to cache directory so native library can read them.
        // N.B.: If contents of assets folder changes, be sure to increment the
        // versionCode integer in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
        AssetHelper assetHelper = new AssetHelper(getAssets());        
        assetHelper.cacheAssetFolder(getInstance(), "Data");
    }
}

public class ARSimple extends ARActivity {


    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 133;
    /**
     * A custom renderer is used to produce a new visual experience.
     */
    private SimpleRenderer simpleRenderer = new SimpleRenderer();

    /**
     * The FrameLayout where the AR view is displayed.
     */
    private FrameLayout mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mainLayout = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        //if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
            //if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) { //ASK EVERY TIME - it's essential!
        //  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        //          new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
        //          MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        //}

        // When the screen is tapped, inform the renderer and vibrate the phone
        mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                simpleRenderer.click();

                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(40);
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * Provide our own SimpleRenderer.
     */
    @Override
    protected ARRenderer supplyRenderer() {
        if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No camera permission - restart the app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        return new SimpleRenderer();
    }

    /**
     * Use the FrameLayout in this Activity's UI.
     */
    @Override
    protected FrameLayout supplyFrameLayout() {
        return (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);     
    }

    private boolean checkCameraPermission() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleRenderer extends ARRenderer {

    private int markerID = -1;

    private Cube cube = new Cube(40.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f);
    private float angle = 0.0f;
    private boolean spinning = false;

    @Override
    public boolean configureARScene() {

        markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single;Data/patt.hiro;80");
        if (markerID < 0) return false;

        return true;

    }

    public void click() {
        spinning = !spinning;
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix(), 0);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        if (ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(markerID)) {

            gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerTransformation(markerID), 0);

            gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            cube.draw(gl);
            gl.glPopMatrix();

            if (spinning) angle += 5.0f;
        }


    }
}
```